# why the mysql results are not same

Tags: mysql, sql

i want select a tree by code,but  when i change the data id,the results are different。

Execute the following sql:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tree`;
CREATE TABLE `tree`  (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_code` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of tree
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `tree` VALUES (1, '0', '中国', '1');
INSERT INTO `tree` VALUES (2, '1', '四川省', '2');
INSERT INTO `tree` VALUES (3, '2', '成都市', '3');
INSERT INTO `tree` VALUES (4, '3', '武侯区', '4');
INSERT INTO `tree` VALUES (5, '4', '红牌楼', '5');
INSERT INTO `tree` VALUES (6, '1', '广东省', '6');
INSERT INTO `tree` VALUES (7, '1', '浙江省', '7');
INSERT INTO `tree` VALUES (8, '6', '广州市', '8');
```

select by the fllowing sql :

```
  SELECT v1.code,v1.id, v1.p_code, v1.name,@pv
      FROM tree v1,
      (SELECT @pv :='1') v2
      WHERE (v1.code = @pv) or  ( FIND_IN_SET(v1.p_code, @pv) and @pv := concat(@pv, ',', v1.code) )
```

sql results(this results is i want) :
[image]

now when i change the parent id(1 -> 10)(id value is greater than the son id value), do the sql select. results changed:
[image]

[image]

why? it is so confusing

Comment: Can you please correct the missing image and also what is parent and son? Is p_code & code column?

Comment: The use of variables for this purpose is not recommended.  In MySQL 8+, use a recursive CTE.  In earlier versions, a stored procedure or looping in the application layer.

Comment: mysql version is 5.6   column is p_code and code

Comment: Generally. When you use user-defined variables for iterational calculations then the rows processing order is critical. For rows processing order to be deterministic you **MUST** add `ORDER BY` clause into your query, and the expression used in it must be **UNIQUE** for the processed rowset.

Comment: In your particular case. The order of output list expressions evaluation is not documented but practically it matches the expression order in the query text. From the other side the order of WHERE clause list expressions evaluation is not documented too but practically it may NOT match the expression order in the query. Moreover, it depends on the execution plan which is dynamic and may be altered in any time (due to this your 1st query which gives now the result which is correct may easily return another output after the next execution if the plan will evaluate `@pv :=` before `FIND_IN_SET`).